# "There are a good many scholars ..." is it right?

Tags: articles, word-order, indefinite-article

In "Seeing like a state" of James C.Scott there is a sentence at the beginning of a paragraph (Acknowledgements xi):

> There are a good many scholars whose writings opened up new
>   perspectives for me or provided outstanding analyses of issues that I
>   could not have hoped to study so comprehensively on my own.

What worries me is *a good many scholars*. Is this some type of inversion or ancient English? Is this grammatically right? Why is **a** here?
I thought that appropriate version would be *There are many good scholars*. Am I wrong?

Comment: NOTE: _"good many scholars"_ is perfectly correct and grammatical, it is not ancient English, it is not an inversion, and it does _not_ have the same meaning as _"many good scholars"_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a quantifying expression, *a good Q* with *Q* a quantifier:

> a good many
>   a good few
>   a good number of
>   a good deal of

Here *a good* acts as an intensifier, like *very* or *quite a*. The same phrase with measure nouns (*a good handful*, *a good yard*, *a good gallon*) marks the measure as “full”, perhaps even more:

*A good many* and *a good few* are comparatively rare today, but were fairly common from the middle of the 19th century to the middle of the 20th; and *a good number* and *a good deal* are still current.

Comment: I disagree only on _a good many_. I reckon it's still widely used, although my reckoning is based on no particular research, just gut.

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+good+many%2Ca+good+few%2Ca+good+number+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20good%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20good%20few%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20good%20number%20of%3B%2Cc0) shows it in pretty steep decline since WWI, and that sorts with my experience: except among people who read a lot of older fiction I think it's mostly been displaced by "a whole lot", "a whole bunch" and the like.

Comment: I have a distrust of the ngram in instances of popular usage, which I'm not convinced is reflected in "lots of books". A BNC, GloWbE, or COCA return would be more convincing (to me, of course) and just as soon as I can figger out how in tarnation to form the incantations at those sites, I'll run a query.

Comment: @P.E.Dant GN by and large gets more heavily weighted towards popular use the later you run it, simply because of changes in the publishing industry. COCA is pretty useless as a direct index to colloquial use (its 'spoken' corpus is mostly news broadcasts and interviews) so I think you'd do better to look at fiction. BNC is far superior.

Comment: Don't you think news broadscasts etc. reflect popular usage? I should think that such broadcasts _must_ gibe with popular usage lest they be perceived as "toney". What about a GloWbE website query? Too many NNS-authored samples? The Ngram is pretty convincing, though. Dammit.

Comment: @P.E.Dant They 'reflect' popular usage--so, indeed, does much contemporary academic writing--but until quite recently they were largely pre-scripted; and most interviews are with highly educated people who have said the same thing hundreds of times before and have lots of practice casting their thoughts into fairly well-considered well-crafted expressions.

Comment: That may be one of the reasons why transcripts of *sports commentators* seem to figure disproportionately in "first citations" for many colloquial usages. I'm quite willing to believe such people really do live in a more linguistically flexible / innovative environment, but the mere fact that they're obliged to produce a stream of utterances on the fly in an inherently unpredictable context may make them naturally more prone to use constructions they might not have chosen in a more carefully-planned situation. Constructions which may thereby gain additional currency among listeners.

Answer (score -1):

You're exactly right. It's an older English convention and is synonymous with *There are many scholars*. "Many a thing" is synonymous with "Many things", while "Many a *good* thing" is synonymous with "Substantially many things". As @StoneyB said, *good* is an adjective modifying nominalized *many*, not *things*.

Comment: You have to use the singular indirect article ('a') and a _singular_ noun for it to make sense. Not "many a things" or "many some things", but "many a thing".

Comment: This is exactly right. Why the downvote? It ticks me off to see incorrect downvotes. Goodness.

Comment: @Lambie I'm the downvoter, because this is wrong. *A good many X* does not mean "many good X"--it means "a substantial number of X". *Good* is an adjective modifying nominalized *many*.

Comment: @StoneyB I've edited my post

Comment: _"There are a good many scholars"_ is **not** synonymous with _"There are many scholars."_